# jruby-jms-1.3.0-java gem create_destination method throws error "undefined method `java_kind_of?

Tags: upgrade, jruby

create_destination method in jruby-jms-1.3.0-java gem(latest version) with jRuby 9.4.5.0 still have java_kind_of?(JMS::Destination) which is giving me error:

```
"undefined method `java_kind_of?' for #<Java::OrgApacheActivemqCommand::ActiveMQQueue:0x70d2433a>", "Did you mean?  java_send (NoMethodError)"]
```

I am calling create_destination, but it gives this error for consumer only.

```
/usr/jruby-9.4.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jruby-jms-1.3.0-java/lib/jms/session.rb:180:in `create_destination'
/usr/jruby-9.4.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jruby-jms-1.3.0-java/lib/jms/session.rb:350:in `consumer'
```

jms_consume method:

```
def jms_consume _queue = self.receive_queue, _selector = ''
      consumed = nil
      JMS::Connection.session(@jms_config) { |session|
        session.queue(_queue){ |q|
          session.consumer(:destination => q, :selector=>_selector) { |consumer|
            message = consumer.get(:timeout => 5000) 
            log.debug "Consumed message #{message.data}" unless message.nil?
            consumed = message != nil ? message.data : nil
          }
        }
      }
      consumed
    end
```

As per [this issue](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/6862), java_kind_of has been removed and have to be replaced with kind_of.
It works if I change it, but have to change it with every installation of tool.

How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the last release of the [jruby-jms gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jruby-jms) was in January 2019, and the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/reidmorrison/jruby-jms) was archived in January 2020.  It doesn't look like this project is maintained anymore.

If you still want to continue using this gem, one option could be to [fork and fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582728/forking-a-gem-for-a-rails-project) yourself.  The actual fix in this case is simple: just search the gem code for any uses of `java_kind_of?` and replace them with `kind_of?`.

If you also [release the fixed gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753461/what-are-the-ethics-etiquette-of-forking-someone-elses-github-project-to-rele) to the public, instead of just maintaining a private fork, this also allows others to benefit from your improvements and maintenance, and perhaps to contribute their own improvements back.

---

Alternatively, if you really don't want to fork the gem, another option is to monkey-patch the removed `java_kind_of?` method back, [as suggested by enebo](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/6862#issuecomment-1549807507) on the issue thread you linked in your question:

```rb
class Object
  alias java_kind_of? kind_of?
end
```

You will, of course, need to apply this patch before calling any code that uses the `java_kind_of?` method.  A safe place to do that is either before requiring the `jms` gem or, if you're using e.g. Bundler to load the gem, in your application startup code before loading Bundler.  (In a Rails app, putting this code in an initializer would likely also work, at least unless you somehow use the `jms` gem in your app startup code.)

Of course, a compatibility patch like this is really only a temporary fix.  The real problem is that you're using an unmaintained gem dependency which is likely to accumulate more and more "bit rot" over time.  Unless someone else just happens to step up to fork the gem and take over its maintenance, eventually you'll likely have to decide between forking and maintaining it yourself or giving up on it and switching to some alternative solution.

Comment: IImari Karonen, Thank you for the suggestion. I will give it a try to both the approaches you mentioned and further add the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it as suggested above:

1. adding *monkey_patch.rb* and add it where application is initialized. (before requiring the `jms` gem).
2. Fork the [*jruby-jms*](https://github.com/reidmorrison/jruby-jms) and update [*session.rb*](https://github.com/reidmorrison/jruby-jms/blob/master/lib/jms/session.rb) and [*create custom gem*](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)

`monkey_patch.rb` (in same directory as `application.rb`):

```
class Object
  alias java_kind_of? kind_of?
end
```

add following line in `application.rb` (initializing the application)

```
require_relative 'monkey_patch.rb'
```